# awk: BEGIN{print(n1<n2)?"1":"0"}: No such file or directory

Tags: awk

I'm using `top` and Awk to get `cpu_idle` num in a monitor script; when the idle is 100, it prints out some errors, like this:

```
no 0 97.7
awk: BEGIN{print(n1<n2)?"1":"0"}: No such file or directory
yes 100
```

Below is my script:

```
minidle=5
while true;
do
    cpu_idle=`top -b -n1 | grep -o "[0-9]*.[0-9]\+% idle"|awk -F% '{print $1}'`
    r=`awk -v n1=$cpu_idle -v n2=$minidle 'BEGIN{print(n1<n2)?"1":"0"}'`
    if [ $cpu_usage == 100 ]; then
        echo "yes" $r $cpu_idle
    else
        echo "no" $r $cpu_idle
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

How can I solve this problem?

I've tried to set the `cpu_idle` directly to 100, just like

```
cpu_idle=100
```

there is no error anymore. Is there anything I missed?

Comment: try running with `set -vx`. you could get a similar error if `$minidle` does not expand to a single word, for example

Comment: Copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about. That will almost certainly fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

When the idle percentage is exactly 100%, the output from `top` is slightly different.

```
root@f07b09fa265e:/# top -b -n1
top - 11:45:14 up 2 days,  7:24,  0 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
Tasks:   2 total,   1 running,   1 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :   7846.6 total,   6308.3 free,    635.8 used,    902.5 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   1024.0 total,   1024.0 free,      0.0 used.   6957.3 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
    1 root      20   0    4624   3584   3072 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.06 bash
   18 root      20   0    7180   3200   2816 R   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 top
```

Here is a refactoring which fixes not only the immediate error, but also several other code smells.

```
minidle=5
while true; do
    # Use modern $(...) command substitution syntax
    # Avoid grep | awk; prefer sed for this simple task
    cpu_idle=$(top -b -n1 |
        sed -En 's/.*([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)(% idle| id,).*/\1/p')
    # Proper quoting
    r=$(awk -v n1="$cpu_idle" -v n2="$minidle" 'BEGIN{print(n1<n2)?"1":"0"}')
    # Don't repeat yourself
    # Use = or -eq, not ==
    [ "$cpu_usage" = 100 ] && result=yes || result=no
    # Proper quoting
    echo "$result $r $cpu_idle"
    sleep 1
done
```

If your `sed` does not support the `-E` option, you have to resort to a slightly uglier regular expression. Maybe try `sed -r` before you go that route (neither of these options is properly standardized).

I'm guessing `$cpu_usage` should be `$cpu_idle`, too, or is there a third variable which your current script uses but does not show in your question? Should it contain a string (and does that string have decimals after the 100) or should it be a number (in which case the comparison should use `-eq`, not `=`)? Perhaps a better solution still is to refactor all of this to Awk.

```
while true; do
    top -b -n1 |
    awk -v minidle="$minidle" '
        match($0, /([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)(% idle| id)/, n) { cpu_idle=n[1] }
        END { print (cpu_idle == 100 ? "yes" : "no"), (cpu_idle<minidle?"1":"0"), cpu_idle }'
    sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to use `vmstat` which is strictly command line tool. From other side `top` is more visual tool:

```
minidle=5
while true
do
vmstat 1 2|tail -1|awk -v mi=$minidle '{a=$(NF-2);if(a<mi) print  "yes", a; else print  "no", a}'

sleep 1
done
```

Also you never assign value to `cpu_usage` variable. Also in bash is used `-eq` when you compare numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
minidle=5
while :; do
 mpstat |
   awk -v midle=$minidle '
       /all/{
             print (int($NF) == 100 ? "yes" : "no"),
                   (int($NF) < midle ? 1 : 0),
                   int($NF)
       }
   '
 sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!